# Issue with WooCommerce Cart & Checkout Layout

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

Wordpress Version: 4.9.7

WooCommerce Version: 3.4.3

WooCommerce has caused layout issues with the Cart & Checkout page. It's any WooCommerce page with a table.

The table with classes of:

```
shop_table shop_table_responsive cart woocommerce-cart-form__contents
```

is causing issues. The WooCommerce CSS for the table sets a width of 100%, however the actual width shows as 4870px. The theme's parent element width is set as 1100px.

Why is the table's width much larger than that set by the theme?

There are no CSS declarations after that overwrites.

There are no issues with the products page or product page.

Answer (score 0):

You can always remove default WooCommerce styles, the risk is that you may use some. Anyway it worth the check:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_empty_array' );
```

If this doesn't help, maybe post a link to the page so we can inspect the layout and CSS?

Comment: Thanks. I've removed all WooCommerce styles and the remaining style sheet is the theme's CSS. The table's width is still stretching the parent. I will try and get a link, the site is in development locally at the moment.

Comment: try to set the parent as position: relative;

Comment: The issue was the WooCommerce content was surrounded in a pre tag! Not sure why it's there either! Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  The root cause I found was caused by copy/pasting the short code from the woocomerce website directly into a visual editor (WPBakery Page Builder in my case).

The copy picked up the `<pre>` tag from the [source](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-2) and applied it when pasting, triggering a change of the style to `preformatted` without me noticing.

Two solutions to fix - depending on your Visual Editor and preference.

1. Simply changing back to the default `Paragraph` setting,

- Highlight `[woocomerce_cart]`
- Select `Paragraph` from the drop-down styles list
- Update/Publish!

2. OR, Remove the `<pre>` tags manually

- Change to a 'text' only view of the page code
- Remove surrounding `<pre>` tags leaving `[woocomerce_cart]`
- Update/Publish!

Sorry, can't embed images yet...

**Image showing issue:**
[image]

**Image showing manual solution:**
[image]

This should work for any other short codes pasted in as well, including `[woocomerce_checkout]` as mentioned in OP.

Answer (score 0):

You might have unnecessary pre tag as a wrapper, causing the table to stretch:

```
<pre>[woocommerce_cart]</pre>
```

In order to remove it, you may install "Disable Gutenberg" plugin, then edit the Cart Page in Text tab, leaving only:

```
[woocommerce_cart]
```